# Putting class static members definition into cpp file -- technical limitation?

Tags: c++, static, declaration

one of my "favorite" annoyance when coding in C++ is declaring some static variable in my class and then looking at compilation error about unresolved static variable (in earlier times, I was always scared as hell what does it mean).

I mean classic example like:

Test.h

```
class Test
{
private:
  static int m_staticVar;
  int m_var;
}
```

Test.cpp

```
int Test::m_staticVar;
```

What makes it in my eyes even more confusing is the syntax of this definition, you can't use 'static' word here (as static has different meaning when used in cpp, sigh) so you have no idea (except the knowledge static member vars work like that) why on earth there's some int from Test class defined in this way and why m_var isn't.

To your knowledge / opinion, why is that? I can think of only one reason and that is making linker life easier -- i.e. for the same reason why you can't use non-integral constants (SomeClass m_var = something). But I don't like an idea of bending language features just because some part of compilation chain would have hard time eating it...

Comment: Really not clear what your question is here.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I was always under the impression that there's no need to go list the static variable outside of the class declaration unless you want to initialize it to a specific value. VS2008 doesn't complain about you class definition, but that's just one compiler and so it doesn't prove that I'm right ...

Comment: I agree, it is annoying having to do this. I don't think the definition in the cpp is particularly confusing, once you've been told what to do to make the linker happy with static member.

Comment: @Praetorian: It is not a compiler's business. If you don't define the static, it results in a *linker* error, which I also get with VC++ 2005 (don't have anything newer).

Comment: @UncleBens, I got the VS2008 linker to throw an error; I have to try and access the static variable for it to complain.

Comment: @Praetorian: Same probably with many other compilers. If a symbol is not used, the linker doesn't need it.

Comment: @Praetorian: if it's a static const integer member, initialised in the class declaration, and you never do anything that needs to take its address, then it doesn't need a separate definition - it's treated as a compile-time constant. Otherwise, it's an object, and each object must to be defined in just one place, i.e. in one source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is just the way it works.  You've only declared the static member in the .h file.  The linker needs to be able to find exactly one *definition* of that static member in the object files it links together.  You can't put the definition in the .h file, that would generate multiple definitions.

UPDATE: C++17 can solve this with an [inline variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).

Comment: Technically, you can put it in the .h-file as long as the file is not included in more than one compilation unit. :)

Comment: On the other hand, it is OK to have multiple definitions of a template (or an inline function?) and have the linker pick one...

Comment: @UncleBens: C++ is never consistent. That's part of its charm.

Answer (score 1):

First, from compiler's point of view, this is perfectly reasonable. Why redundant keyword where it is not needed?

Second, I'd recommend against static members in C++. Before everybody jumps, I will try to explain.

Well, you are not going to have any public static data members (very rarely useful). In any case, most classes have their own CPP file. If so, a static global, IMO is preferable over a private static member for reasons of dependency reduction. Unlike non-static private data, the static ones are not part of the interface, and there's very little reason why should the user of the h file ever have to recompile, or at all see these members.

Comment: You probably want `s/static global/variable in the anonymous namespace/`. Those cause less problems with templates (they have unique external linkage; static globals have no external linkage).