# Do c++ guarantee header-initialized static const member to share a single instance across compile units and libraries?

Tags: c++, static-members, c++98

Let's consider a code

header:

```
class uid
{
public:
    uid () {++i; }
    static int i;
};

class foo
{
public:
    const static uid id;
}
```

source:

```
static int uid::i = 0;
```

The header could be included into several source files, shared between compiler units and libraries.

Is it guaranteed that there would be only one instance off `foo::id`, that `foo::id::id()` would be called once at run-time and, the most important thing, would `foo::id.i` be the same everywhere in the program and it's libraries? On the other hand another shared header could have `bar` class with it's own `static const uid id` which is expected to differ from `foo`'s one. Is it also guaranteed? If so, where actually `foo::id` symbol is stored, especially in case of shared (dynamic-linked) libraries.

On some reason c++ disables

```
class foo
{
public:
    const static int id = create_uid(); // forbidden
}
```

allowing only compile-time const initialisation or initialization in source file. So there was some reason to disable this kind of approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is guaranteed.

The symbol lives in the translation unit built from the source file where the object was defined. Indeed, that's *why* we have to define it in one!

The linker makes sure all the references from the copies of that header across your project all match up to the sole definition.

As for why C++ doesn't let you initialise static members inline: it *does*, but not in C++98. You need C++17 for that.

Comment: There could be actually no source file where ```foo```'s members are defined (and even no ```foo``` object at all) - everything is in header. So one may afraid that a compiler could store own copy of ```foo::id``` in each source file where the header is included. Yes, it's about c++98.

Comment: @Nick If there's no definition of `foo`, then there is no `foo` and your program will not be buildable (you'll get a linker error; you can test that for yourself). No need for fear. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo [Not exclusively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46874055/4386278)

Comment: To be equally fair, I didn't consider `inline` :-) Initializing a `const static` is ok in c++98 too afaik, but calling a function to initialize it isn't.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was thinking of NSDMIs for C++11 anyway  Ah well.

Comment: there used to be a caveat allowing integral types (int) but not float, double to be initialized inline. was that restriction also dropped with C++17?

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface You can pretty much [do whatever you like](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbb90f78a2b55b37) now. Though I'm not sure your premise is true. _(Edit: never mind; [it is](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03bc1ac061ba2818))_ C++11 allowed it with `constexpr`.