# Confusion about declaration and definition of static const data memebers

Tags: c++, static, language-lawyer, variable-declaration

Scott Meyers writes in Effective Modern C++ (Item 30, at page 210) that there's

> no need to define integral `static const` data members in classes; declarations alone suffice,

then the sample code is

```cpp
class Widget {
  public:
    static const std::size_t MinVals = 28; // MinVals' declaration;
    ...
};
...                                        // no defn. for MinVals
std::vector<int> widgetData;
widgetData.reserve(Widget::MinVals);       // use of MinVals
```

I was convinced that `static const std::size_t MinVals = 28;` is declaration ***and also*** a definition, as it is giving a value to `MinVals`, but the comment seems to claim that's only a declaration; the second comment actually claims there's no definition. The text after the code, indeed reads

> `MinVals` lacks a definition.

Which confirms that `static const std::size_t MinVals = 28;` is not a definition, so I'm a bit confused.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) doesn't help me much (my bold-italic):

> If a `static` data member of integral or enumeration type is ***declared*** `const` (and not `volatile`), it can be initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a constant expression, right inside the class definition:
>
> ```
> struct X
> {
>    const static int n = 1;
>    const static int m{2}; // since C++11
>    const static int k;
> };
> const int X::k = 3;
> ```

but first two lines in the class look definitions to me.

The same goes for a following example on cppreference:

> ```
> struct X {
>     static const int n = 1;
>     static constexpr int m = 4;
> };
> const int *p = &X::n, *q = &X::m; // X::n and X::m are odr-used
> const int X::n;             // … so a definition is necessary
> constexpr int X::m;         // … (except for X::m in C++17)
> ```

where I'd have said `static const int n = 1;` is a definition, but it is not, based on the second to last comment.

Comment: From n4835.pdf [class.static.data] (2) `The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class definition is not a definition [...]`. But (3) is directly for integral types with an initializer and this paragraph does not help if this is a declaration or definition.

Comment: Thinking at it again, @AndyG, I don't there's something else to explicitly state to make my question clear. The title begins as _Confusion about_. That's it. I'm confused about that and I asking for help. _Confusion about [...]. Can you help me understand this?_

Comment: C++17 introduces `inline static`, and it's awesome.

Comment: [recent, related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61781901/1132334)

Comment: In hindsight, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749071/why-does-a-static-data-member-need-to-be-defined-outside-of-the-class) is also related.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> *no need to define integral static const data members in classes; declarations alone suffice,*

Declarations alone suffice only if that object is not [ODR-used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19630570/3953764), that is, if a data member is not used in a context that would require its address to exist (like binding to a reference or applying operator `&`). The presence of an initializer *does not* equal a definition.

In the example from the book, it's clear that `MinVals` is not ODR-used, i.e., the compiler can use its value directly, without having to create an object in memory, and so the statement:

```
widgetData.reserve(Widget::MinVals);
```

becomes:

```
widgetData.reserve(28);
```

If, however, in any other place, `MinVals` were ODR-used, that would make the program ill-formed.

All other examples from cppreference clearly indicate when a value is ODR-used and a definition is required, and when not:

```
struct X
{
    const static int n = 1;
    const static int m{2}; // since C++11
    const static int k;
};
const int X::k = 3;
```

`n` and `m` are declarations with initializers. An attempt to obtain the address of either `n` or `m` should fail.

```
struct X {
    static const int n = 1;
    static constexpr int m = 4;
};
const int *p = &X::n, *q = &X::m;
const int X::n;
constexpr int X::m;
```

Expressions `&X::n` and `&X::m` count as ODR-use of `n` and `m`, respectively (that is, an address is requested). For a `constexpr` static data members, a definition was required prior to C++17. From C++17, `static constexpr` data members are implicitly `inline`, which means, no out-of-class definition is needed, as they are definitions themselves.

Comment: The critical phrase here is [initializing declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#def:initializing_declaration).

Comment: Answer accepted, but I have two doubts about the very first paragraph in your answer. You write _Declarations alone suffice only if [...]_; do you refer specifically to declarations of _ integral static const data members_, or to declarations in general? You finish the paragraph with _The presence of an initializer does not equal a definition_, which makes it look like a consequence of what precedes it, but I don't see the connection. Maybe you can clarify that first paragraph?

Comment: That depends on what kind of declarations you ask about. You can feel free not to define a static data member (either const or not), and only declare it as long as you don't ODR-use it. You can feel free not to define a function, as long as it's not called. You can feel free not to define a class, as long as you do not use it in a context that requires its full definition to exist. You are allowed to put an initializer to integral const static data members, but it doesn't make it a definition. It's valid, and allows the compiler to perform optimization, as long as that entity is not ODR-used.

Comment: Don't focus only on the syntax. `static const int i = 0;` means something different whether it's in a class scope or in the global scope. It's semantics what eventually matters, and it results from both *syntax* and *context*.

Comment: And the standard makes it explicitly a non-definition in [\[basic.def\]/p2.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2.3), unless you put also the `inline` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at this [Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), it appears that your example falls into a grey area. While there is no *explicit* mention of lines such as:

```cpp
    static const std::size_t MinVals = 28;
```

There is an example given which is *very* similar:

> **6.1 Declarations and definitions**
>   ...
>   2 A declaration is a definition unless
>   ...
>   2.3 — it declares a non-inline static data member in a class definition
>   ...
>   Example: All but one of the following are definitions:
>   
>   int a; // defines a
>   extern const int c = 1; // defines c
>   ...

The second example is *close* to your code, but with a significant difference in having the `extern` qualifier. Also, note that the above states that a declaration is (by default) also a *definition* unless one of the listed conditions applies; I would say (though I'm no Language-Lawyer) that none of those conditions are met *exactly* in your case, so your declaration **is also** a definition.

<sup>NOTE: The linked document is only a *draft* standard; make sure to read the 'disclaimer' given at the foot of its first page!</sup>

Comment: But the /2.3 condition *does* apply here!

Comment: @DavisHerring That's my 'grey area'. I think it applied literally but the term 'inline' *can* be ambiguous: i.e. **either** an explicit `inline` qualifier **or** 'in body' (code placed inside the class definition). I'm probably only adding to the confusion, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole, since _inline_ in 2.3 is not code-formatted, I agree with you that _non-inline_ means _not written inside the class definition_, which would mean that 2.3 doesn't apply to my (well, Scott Meyers' book's) case.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I would agree but, as I said, I'm no Language-Lawyer. This conversation could easily become iterative, if not recursive. Further, if the first two examples are definitions, then I really can't see why yours is not.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: The standard does not use “inline” to mean “defined (or initialized) in a class”.  It also doesn’t use code font to refer to *properties* (like inline or constexpr) that can be applied/implied other than by a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) Chapter "12.2.3.2 Static data members":

> The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

By using it, it shall be defined.