# Why do static member variables need to be declared inline while static member functions don't?

Tags: c++, class, static, inline

I'm working through exercises in a book and have written the following class:

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

class Box {

    private:
        double length {1.0},
               width  {1.0},
               height {1.0};
        
        inline static std::size_t object_count {};
    
    public:
        Box() = default;
        Box(double length, double width, double height);
        explicit Box(double side);
        Box(const Box& box);
        
        double volume() const;
        bool has_larger_volume(const Box& other) const;
        friend double surface_area(const Box& box);

        double get_length() const { return this->length; };
        double get_width()  const { return this->width;  };
        double get_height() const { return this->height; };

        void set_length(double length) { if (length > 0) this->length = length; };
        void set_width(double width)   { if (width > 0)  this->width = width;   };
        void set_height(double height) { if (height > 0) this->height = height; };

        static std::size_t get_object_count() { return Box::object_count; }

};

#endif
```

My question, specifically pertains to the use of the `inline` keyword in this context. I understand that static member variables are created once at runtime regardless of the existence of class objects. `object_count` would be defined multiple times, once for each translation unit and thus it is necessary to qualify it with `inline` to allow this behavior.

But, why is it not necessary to qualify `get_object_count()` with inline as well? Why doesn't that break ODR? Are all member functions implicitly inline regardless of being declared as static?

Comment: Part of your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874055/why-is-inline-required-on-static-inline-variables). As for the member functions, when they are defined inside the class definition they are implicitly inline (no keyword required).

Comment: See the [top of this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline).